# Search box not returning any results

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search, search-results, enterprise-search

I have a SharePoint 2010 solution.

I've started the search service application, enabled crawling, did a full crawl, and created a Search Center Sub site. I've also set up a crawl rule. Looking at the Crawl logs, there is data that is indexed, and ready to be returned in a search result.

However, when I go to my search center subsite on my sharePoint site, and search for a term, no results come back. I've tried several key words that are on the site, but no results.

Does anyone have any suggestions why there are no results being returned in search?

**UPDATE**: When I create the Search Center page, I was not sure what to enter for the URL field, so I just wrote "Search Center". Does this make a difference?

Comment: Have you configured `Local SharePoint Sites` content source with the correct Start Address?

Comment: Yes, the site address, and others are properly written in the Local SharePoint Sites content source. There are results indexed from this content source, but they do not appear in the results page.

Comment: It's like they are somehow not connected ...

Comment: Check this http://blog.dafran.ca/post/2011/07/02/SharePoint-does-not-return-any-search-results.aspx

Comment: What is the crawl rule for? Does the account you are searching with have access to the content you are searching for?

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I had the same issue today. But it resolved after I removed all Content Sources and cleared the index and tried setting up a crawl.

Comment: I am not able to delete the Local SharePoint sites Content Source. I can delete everything else. Doing so, re-adding, and crawling again did not help.