# Search not showing any results. Not even for '*'

Tags: search-results

We know this a very common question which as resolutions already given like below. However these are not working for us;

[WebSite search does not find any result](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172805/website-search-does-not-find-any-result)

[Search Results Web Part is not showing any results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174181/search-results-web-part-is-not-showing-any-results)

[Search box not returning any results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122723/search-box-not-returning-any-results)

amongst others...

We are banging our heads for hours now.

Content gets crawled correctly. No errors
However Search just doesn't show any result. Not even for **"*"**

We have Followed the below MSDN link to configure Search Service Application

[Create and configure search service application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/search/create-and-configure-a-search-service-application)

Then set Service connections in Central Admin for the Web Application
[image]

**Then confirmed the Crawl URL is same as the URL of Application in Alternate Access Mapping for Default Zone**

**[Update]**
Topology status;
[image]

Crawl Status
[image]

Kindly let know are we missing any thing. Kindly let know if any further details required.

Comment: Do you have all green checkmarks in "Search Application Topology" in the search admin page?

Comment: In the Crawl Log do you see "Successes"? And is the number reasonable for your number of documents, pages, etc?

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for the response. Have updated the post with your asked information. Crawl has many successes and Topology has all green checkmarks. Please see details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Bad,

All by mistake while i was creating the Site Collection had given a different user as Site Collection Administrator than the user used for Content source account. After setting the Site Col admin account same as the content source account. results started showing as expected.